# index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list in TFS Power Tools

Tags: customization, visual-studio-power-tools

"index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list"

This error occurs when customize workitem using TFS Power Tools in TFS 2013.

How can i solve ??

Comment: What changes do you make on the work item definition? Can you share the customized WIT XML file?

Comment: Please Share your email ID

Comment: How can i share file???

Comment: You can send to my email: v-eddche at microsoft dot com

Answer (score 0):

Export the WIT definition file you are working on and check if there is duplicate rule in it. Refer to this link for details: [index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list at TFS](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0ac1189d-6489-4ee5-ba3d-94cdab4ab797/index-zero-based-must-be-greater-than-or-equal-to-zero-and-less-than-the-size-of-the-argument-list?forum=tfspowertools).

Answer (score 0):

My Problem is solved. thanks to @Eddie -MSFT for his cordial help. i have attached image. **courtesy by Eddie -MSFT.**

**Steps are given below:**
1. Export the WIT using witadmin exportwitid command in command prompt.
2. Check the data in XML file.
3. Remove [duplicate data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6YTJ.jpg) that are mismatch as like 
4. Import the WIT importwitid command,
5. if any problems occurs like as TF212019 or TF237070 the check the XML file specially [check values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZP8G.jpg).
6. Noted that: Neglect to Use '&' value. there can show error.
7. then you can successfully import the wit & reopen the Visual Studio with administrator privilege.
8. Hope Problem will be solved.